Bluetooth reverse tither -> local services -> NAP settings -> apply button greyed out problem
I want to set up Bluetooth on my Ubuntu computer to share its internet connection to my mobile device.  (Which is the reverse direction of the usual tethering).
So, from the Blueman icon (I'm using blueman-applet 2.1.2 in Ubuntu 20.04) I click "local services", then I get this window:

Now if I type in my actual Ethernet IP address, the "Apply" button will immediately grey out, but if I change the IP address just a little, to another random address, it will NOT be greyed out.
I tried changing the PAN and DUN setting buttons below, no difference.
The dnsmasq option is a forced choice.
I read somewhere that suggests the problem may not be with Blueman but with some write privilege settings in some folders containing settings... but I'm not sure about this.  Any ideas?
